# how can draw this picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I tried to do that but :(

[image]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,line width=0.8pt]
%les sommets
\draw (0,0)node (0)[]{$\bf 0$};
\draw (2,0)node (1)[]{$\bf 1$};
\draw (4,0)node (2)[]{$\bf 2$};
\draw (6,0)node (x)[]{$\bf x$};
\draw (8,0)node (n-1)[]{$\bf n-1$};
\draw (10,0)node (n)[]{$\bf n$};
\draw (11,0)node (n+1)[]{$\bf n+1$};
%les fleches
\draw [->] (n)to [bend right] (n-1);
\draw [->] (n)to [bend right] (x);
\draw [->] (n)to [bend right] (1);
\draw [->] (n)to [bend right] (2);
\draw [->] (n)to [bend right] (0);
\draw [->] (4)to [bend right] (n+1);
%\draw (-3.5,3.7) node [scale=0.7] {$\alpha_{1}$};
%\draw (-2.5,3.7) node [scale=0.7] {$\alpha_{n-2}$};
%\draw (-1.5,3.7) node [scale=0.7] {$\alpha_{n-1}$};
%\draw (-0.5,3.7) node [scale=0.7] {$\alpha_{n}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

Comment: If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). No one will answer your questions if you don't start doing this...

Answer (score 9):

Here is a slightly different approach, using a `\foreach` loop to place the nodes, and the `quotes` library to add the edge nodes. `\bf` has been deprecated for about 25 years, so I used `\mathbf{..}` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=stealth,line width=0.8pt,
  every edge quotes/.style={font=\footnotesize,pos=0.7,above}
]
%les sommets
\foreach [count=\i] \txt in {0,1,2,\dots,n-1,n,n+1}
   \node (n-\i) at (\i*2,0) {$\mathbf{\txt}$};


\draw [->] (n-6) to[bend right,"$\alpha_n$"] (n-1);
\draw [->] (n-6) to[bend right,"$\alpha_{n-1}$"] (n-2);
\draw [->] (n-6) to[bend right,"$\alpha_{n-2}$"] (n-3);
\draw [->] (n-6) to[bend right,"$\alpha_n$"above left] (n-5);

\draw [->] (n-6) to[bend right,"$\lambda$"{midway,below}] (n-7);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Apart from a complete MWE, you already did most of the work! I only added `node`s in the `\draw ... to` commands.

Additionally, you shouldn't use `\bf`, instead use `\bfseries`. And I've added some `scope`s to make changing options for all nodes in that `scope` easier.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,line width=0.8pt]
%les sommets
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={font=\bfseries}]
    \draw (0,0)  node (0)   {$ 0 $};
    \draw (2,0)  node (1)   {$ 1 $};
    \draw (4,0)  node (2)   {$ 2 $};
    \draw (6,0)  node (x)   {$ x $};
    \draw (8,0)  node (n-1) {$ n-1 $};
    \draw (10,0) node (n)   {$ n $};
    \draw (12,0) node (n+1) {$ n+1 $};
\end{scope}
%les fleches
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={font=\small,midway,below}]
    \draw [->] (n)to [bend right] node{$ a_{1} $} (n-1);
    \draw [->] (n)to [bend right] node{$ a_{n-x} $} (x);
    \draw [->] (n)to [bend right] node{$ a_{n-2} $} (1);
    \draw [->] (n)to [bend right] node{$ a_{n-1} $} (2);
    \draw [->] (n)to [bend right] node{$ a_n $} (0);
    \draw [->] (n)to [bend right] node{$ \lambda $} (n+1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]